# ffmpeg convert images in a folder with no defined start number

Tags: windows, command-line, ffmpeg, batch

I'm setting up a batch file to daily convert a folder of screen captures to video.

I can specify the filename of the screen caps, but I can't get it to reset each day, so say 2 might start at 03213.  Without renaming the files is a way to either

1. get ffmepg to find the start number and go to the oldest newest file or
2. read the start and end file names in the batch file and plug that into the ffmpeg command?

this is my current command:

```
ffmpeg.exe -f image2 -framerate 25 -pattern_type sequence -start_number 00001 -i "Y:\ft\!new_folder!\%%05d.jpg" -c:v libx265 -b:v 5000k -g 100 "Y:\ft\!new_folder!.mp4"
```

Comment: Hi, please try to explain it in another way, in the current form it is not very understandable. Please edit your question and consider adding a list of current files, a list of new files, and the corresponding names of new files after renaming, maybe it could help us understand what you need.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want, but it is understandable that you will need to get the starting and ending number of a sequence in the name of jpg files. Until some edition explains it better, I can propose the ways below to define in a variable the initial and final number of your jpg files.

```bath
@echo off && Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "_New_Folder=Some_Dir_Name" 
set "_InOut=Y:\ft\!_New_Folder!"

for /f delims^= %%i in ('where "!_InOut!:*.jpg" ^| sort /r
    ')do if "!_end!" == "" (set "_end=%%~ni")else set "_start=%%~ni"

ffmpeg.exe -f image2 -framerate 25 -pattern_type sequence -start_number !_start! -i "!_InOut!\%%05d.jpg" ^
    -c:v libx265 -b:v 5000k -g 100 -y "!_InOut!.mp4" -hide_banner -loglevel fatal -nostats 2>&1 | find "),"
 
timeout 5 | (echo\start = %_start% & echo\  end = %_end%) & endlocal
```